# How to remove ampersand and get value from url in php

Tags: php

I have a url in which value is coming with ampersand so i want to get value
from that url but due to ampersand this value is coming wrong.So is there
any way to remove ampersand and get the actual value from the url.Because
i have survey website in which whenever user will complete the survey it will automatically redirect on the callback url,so they use ampersand with
the variable.

**My url is like this:-**

```
http://testdomain.com/webservices/v1/api/survey_submit?ssi=%127%&ssi2=%1.80%
```

**Php code is:-**

```
<?php
echo $_GET['ssi'];
?>
```

its value should come **127** but it is showing wrong value **7%**.Is it
possible to get the value ampersand sign.

Comment: % is used to encode hexadecimal value %12 corresponds to some character in hexadecimal. that's why you're not getting that

Comment: If you are sure that there is only one ampersand, use `strpos()`

Comment: Or, to get the last, get `strrtok()`, but I think that it is the `?` that you should be looking for, if you want to get the URL, minus all parameters - your question is not really clear

Comment: It is giving last digit of e.g. ssi=7.<?php  strtok($_GET['ssi'],'%');?> i want whole value i.e. 127.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look about strtok() at http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php

Comment: It is giving last digit of e.g. ssi=7.<?php  strtok($_GET['ssi'],'%');?> i want whole value i.e. 127.